Best way to test credentials?
I've got a C# app where I need to validate credentials for a DB2 database (V7R3).
The way historically we've done this is to append the credentials to a connection string and actually attempt to connect to the database and just see whether the connection succeeds or fails.
But is there a better way to do that, like an API for testing credentials or something?

Built in, from outside the box, no.
You could build a service that does so.  Such a service would likely use the Generate Profile Token API or Get Profile Handle API to validate the username and password.
Both OPM and ILE versions of the above are listed under the Security-related APIs category of system APIs.

Disappointing but okay, thanks.
